# PHP product price, quantity and size foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i'm trying to create a add product page, where you can add sizes, price and quantity.

now i've created a table with multiple names[] and a hidden input:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-1-2" aria-expanded="false">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
 <tr>  
   <td><input type="text" name="count[]" style="display:none;" />
   <td>Prijs: <input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Prijs van stuk" class="form-control name_list" /></td> 
   <td>Maat: <input type="text" name="size[]" placeholder="Bijv: 36, 38, 40 of 42" class="form-control size_list" /></td>  
   <td>Op voorraad: <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Bijv: 20" class="form-control size_list" /></td>  
   <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><span class="ti-plus" style="font-weight:600;"></span></button></td>
 </tr>  
</table>
</div>
```

i would like to see after submit an array of the table:

```
Array
(
[0] => 
   price    = 10,00
   size     = s
   quantity = 12
[1] => 
   price    = 12,00
   size     = m
   quantity = 18
[2] => 
    price    = 14,00
    size     = l
    quantity = 10
[3] => 
    price    = 16,00
    size     = xl
    quantity = 21
)
```

So i can store them in a database table, but i don't know how to do it.
Can someone help me to push me in the good direction?

i've found probably what i need.

```
    $output = array();
    foreach($_POST['count'] as $key=>$name){
        $output[$key]['price'] =    $_POST['price'][$key];
        $output[$key]['size'] =     $_POST['size'][$key];
        $output[$key]['quantity'] =     $_POST['quantity'][$key];
    }
    echo '<pre>',print_r($output),'</pre>';
```

Comment: what youve found is good now just add the database insertion code into the loop

Answer (score 1):

From your example, the PHP post will receive data as follow:

```
$POST = [ 'price' => [ '12', '11.5'], 
          'size' => [ 's' , 'l'],
          ... ];
```

This is not correct way to receive data, if for example price is skipped from 2nd group, it will be skipped in the post as well. Making data be misrepresented. Suddenly 2nd group will have a price of from 3rd group. As it fills the next key. And the last group will have no price.

If you wish to group by number, you must pass it within the form data, such as:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-1-2" aria-expanded="false">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
 <tr>  
   <td><input type="text" name="order[0][count]" style="display:none;" />
   <td>Prijs: <input type="text" name="order[0][price]" placeholder="Prijs van stuk" class="form-control name_list" /></td> 
   <td>Maat: <input type="text" name="order[0][size]" placeholder="Bijv: 36, 38, 40 of 42" class="form-control size_list" /></td>  
   <td>Op voorraad: <input type="text" name="order[0][quantity]" placeholder="Bijv: 20" class="form-control size_list" /></td>  
   <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><span class="ti-plus" style="font-weight:600;"></span></button></td>
 </tr>  
</table>
</div>
```

It will return post what looks like this:

```
$POST = [ 'order' =>
             0 => ['price' => '11.5', 'size' => 's', ... ],
             ... 
        ];
```

Please test and play around, this is not tested code.

As for saving it to the database, please look into [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). You will most likely need to verify and clean up data. NEVER trust anything coming from anywhere.